# Does the "Smoke" id counts as stealth card?

Tags: android-netrunner

There are several (mostly shaper's) cards with text like "... only by spending credits from stealth cards". For example: [Dai V](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11006). Does the [Ele "Smoke" Scovak](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11066) id itself count as a stealth card for such effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smoke has the subtype "stealth".  As a result, she is a stealth card, and her credit can be used to pay for abilities (like Dai V) that say "Use this ability only by spending credits from stealth cards."

Smoke's ability is effectively a copy of [Cloak](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03041).